# jquery increment variable after drag & drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, increment

I am trying to increment a variable by one after each draggable element is dropped onto a droppable div. Once the desired value is reached, some css will change. I managed to get all of the drag and drop functionality by some miracle, however, this increment thing has got me mired in the muck.
Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Here is the my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KzDLA/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by rearranging your `picDrop` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmarabeas/KzDLA/11/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Patrick. I knew I just needed some new eyes and fresh fingers to look at it.